# What is the Mapbox Expression for "multiply"?

Tags: mapbox-android

Mapbox's Android SDK has an [`Expression`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/expressions/Expression.html) for [`Expression.division()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/expressions/Expression.html#division-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression-), but what is the `static` method for multiplication?

I tried looking for the following `static` methods:

- `Expression.multiply()`
- `Expression.multiplication()`
- `Expression.times()`
- `Expression.multiple()`

But none of these exist.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply two numbers use [`Expression.product()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/expressions/Expression.html#product-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression...-)